# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Tags: python, pandas

data.agg('min')

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

I want to take the minimum value from the data, can anyone help me why is this an error?

Comment: data.min() or data.min().min() or data.values.ravel().min()

Comment: What version of pandas?

Comment: minimum of what data? post data frame first

Answer (score 0):

`.agg` is not a function/method that is usable on a dataframe object. This would be something that you might use on a grouped dataframe, or GroupBy object.

lets investigate looking at mins in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

#initalize our data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, 5, 8, 4], 'b':[3, 2, 1, 1]})

df
   a  b
0  2  3
1  5  2
2  8  1
3  4  1
```

Calling `.min()` on the dataframe will give us the mins by column:

```
df.min()
a    2
b    1
```

Calling `.min(1)` on the dataframe will give us the mins by rows (the 1 refers to the axis, `.min()` assumes an axis of 0 for columns)

```
df.min(1)
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
```

If you want the min of a whole dataframe, you could just call min on the mins of columns.

```
df.min().min()
1
```

If you want the min of a specific column, just call the column and use `.min()`

```
df['a'].min()
2
```